# React Native horizontal scroll menu navigation

Tags: react-native, menu, navigation, react-navigation

[image: Up Bank home screen]

How can I achieve this effect in react native expo? mainly the navigating from one screen to another and with the screen headers at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react-navigation, for example with createMaterialTopTabNavigator.

here https://snack.expo.io/@nordup/react-navigation-top-nav an example on how to do it.

Then you can customize the headers as you prefer: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers

Answer (score 0):

I also found this library that was helpful

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screens-swiper